# Syntax for Writing a Custom Partitioner in Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I understand the idea behind a custom partitioner. In my case, I want to send all same words to a one reducer. I understand I can use the hashcode to do that.

However, I am not sure on the syntax of partitioner in Hadoop API.

Here is the signature :

```
Class Partitioner<KEY,VALUE>
```

How do I choose the Key, Value type? Also Why do I need the Value here? Am I not supposed to just use the key and return an integer based on some logic (hashcode in my case).

Can someone explain with the help of an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Syntax for default partitioner (HashPartitioner) is as below

```
 public class HashPartitioner extends Partitioner {
       public int getPartition(K key, V value, int numReduceTasks) {
              return (key.hashCode() & Integer.MAX_VALUE) % numReduceTasks;
       }
 }
```

Key must be WritableComparable type because framework has to perform sorting based on key and value can be of any Writable type so that framework can serialize and deserialize  them.

Now as you asked the requirement for value type lets take an example of MovieLense case study, in which one file named **ratings.dat** have data in the form 
**userID::movieID::ratings::timestamp** 
In this ratings are rating given by user to the movie ranges from 1-5
Now suppose userID is the key and other are in value part. Now suppose you requirement is that output file from reducer should represent rating, like one file containing all records for rating 1, another for rating 2 so on. Hence your output will have total 5 files representing rating.

So now in partitioner you can take decision on the basis of rating contain in value part to send the record to which reducer, like if rating  equal to 1 then return 0, if 2 then return 1 and so on.
So code will be some how as below

```
public class MoviePartitioner extends Partitioner{

    @Override
    public int getPartition(LongWritable userId, Movie value, int arg2) {

        int rating = Integer.parseInt(value.getMovieRating());
        return rating - 1;  // as rating starts from 1 
    }
}
```